# Resizing images to 2x2

Tags: c++, image, opengl, image-resizing

I've got a texture I'm using in OpenGL 4.6 that I want to scale to 2x2, but I'm not sure how. Is there any way to resize an image in a way so that each pixel in the original image is basically duplicated to create a 2x2 in the resized image? I've tried using photoshop to do this, but the image quality always seems to drop significantly. Or do I have to manually create the image myself?

Comment: Well, upscaling a low resolution image to a higher resolution will always lead to quality loss.

Comment: Can I ask why you think this scaling is necessary?  You're using `OpenGL` so any required scaling (up or down) would normally be left to mipmapping and/or interpolation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to OpenGL, so mipmapping and interpolation are not something I'm very familiar with. I'm trying to resize a background texture for a 2d game, but I got lost on how to do it on OpenGL, even moreso with mipmapping or interpolation.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures) (search for 'Texture Filtering').